# Split a table from a query to many tables (with "DISTINCT")

Tags: mysql, sql

**Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT code, hour(datetime), sum(price)
FROM something
ORDER BY code;
```

I have one result table with 3 columns  `code`, `hour`, `sum`.

I would like to have as many tables as there are different `code`.

a code = a table and each table containing "code" (which will be the same in the table), "hour" and "sum".

Thank you.

**Edit 1 :**

Thank you for each replies.
I don't want to UNION tables, not at all.

@Gordon Linoff : I forgot to say that it's for analytics db (Infinidb) so I know that it's not the right way for a relational DB.

I would like to do this to avoid to have many queries. (one query is more faster than many queries)

What I have :

[image]

What I want : (there is not every tables, just to show)

[image]

Comment: use union operator to concatenate multiple query. [union statement link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: what you mean with "table" ? you want to create tables in mysql from data in "something"? or want to print these tables in, par example, php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your query would more appropriately be written as:

```
SELECT code, hour(datetime), sum(price)
FROM something
GROUP BY code, hour(datetime)
ORDER BY code;
```

If you want a separate result table for each code, you need to create the tables separately.  The basic statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE table_code1 as
    SELECT code, hour(datetime) as hour, sum(price) as price
    FROM something
    WHERE code = 'code1'
    GROUP BY hour(datetime);
```

You would need to put this in a loop for all the codes and use prepared statements for the code.

However, I cannot really think of a good reason why you would want this.  Using the query directly or putting all the codes summaries in a single table makes more sense.  In fact, having multiple tables with the same structure in a database is usually a sign of poor database design.

Comment: I edited my post.  Thank you, I see that GROUP BY was more faster than DISTINCT ;)   I would like that it's the server which treats script, not the client.  Is it possible to create the loop with sql ?

Comment: @Alexis_user . . . Your goal seems like a bad idea.  Just use the base query with an appropriate `where` clause.  Let me repeat:  multiple tables in a database with the same structure is almost always a sign of poor design.  There are some rare cases where this is desirable, but it is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Oh, I understand, I only want temp tables. (like the returned table after a querie)  But ok, I trust you, I'm going to do a loop of SELECT queries !

Answer (score 0):

Use union statement for concate mulitple query

> `SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
>   UNION
>   SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;`

Answer (score 0):

2 ways I can think of:

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    [(create_definition,...)]
    [table_options]
    select_statement

INSERT [LOW_PRIORITY | HIGH_PRIORITY] [IGNORE]
    [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
```

in both cases you are selecting the information you want from `something` and saving that result into a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CURSOR-FETCH-NEXT` to select distinct `code` values from `something` table. See here [CURSOR syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-cursor.html). Inside the cursor do a `SELECT` by the current `code` value.